# MySQL: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I just installed MySQL on my computer and when I try to create a database from the MySQL shell, I get this error:

```
MySQL  JS > CREATE DATABASE databasename;
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a problem with the installation of MySQL?

Comment: What is that `JS >` prompt?  Are you sure you're even running this from MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I can't remember what client it is, but one of the command line clients you get defaults to the JS mode when you start it

Answer (score 175, accepted):

By looking at this thread here, it looks like you might be using the shell in js mode, you might be able to toggle it off by using the switch

```
\sql
```

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,661192,661203#msg-661203

Comment: And just in case it isn't painfully obvious you can tell whether you are in JS mode or SQL mode as there will be a JS or SQL immediately following the initial MySqQL prompt

Comment: but why is the JS mode the default? why is there even a JS mode to begin with?

Comment: That is a good question! In the documentation here https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-shell-8.0-en.pdf it says that javascript is the default mode, but it doesn't say why

Comment: Wow, this was more obscure than expected. Kinda weird that you can't get any help command from JS

Comment: It's stupid that mySQL8 starts in JS mode, where you can't run SQL commands.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just downloaded mysql and wanted to do a very quick test and color me surprised when not even a SELECT 1 worked and instead everything were throwing syntax errors. Who in their right mind decided JS was good default ???

Comment: I get the error when invoking a script from cmd with mac like `mysqlsh -u .. -p .. -h amazon.. < script.sql`. Seems like `mysqlsh` reads the script in `js` mode..

Answer (score 70):

You can type:

```
Mysql JS>  \sql
Mysql SQL>  \connect root@localhost
```

and provide your password.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the MySQL shell so that it loads in \sql mode by default?

Comment: I was on the verge of deleting MySQL, if not for your comment.

Answer (score 8):

Logging in as follows *did* work as shown by Rahul in another answer:

```
Mysql JS>  \sql
Mysql SQL>  \connect root@localhost
```

However, I was able to get `Mysql>` instead of `Mysql JS>` or `Mysql SQL>` by opening the Windows command prompt and entering the following:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 2):

try using
**connect root@localhost**
and then try
**\sql**
to switch to sql mode if the default mode is JS.

Comment: For Mysql JS>  \sql

Comment: How does this answer add anything to the existing and highly upvoted answers? Please do not post redundant answers, but - once you have gained the rep - upvote existing ones instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you would have done the complete User Setup by providing appropriate username and password. Now to initialize to interact with the sql database you need to follow below steps:

1.Using cmd or powershell,first get into sql directory by using `\sql`
2.Now use `\connect root@localhost` to connect the server to SQL MODE. It will ask you to provide password and then save it.

Now you are good to go!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`JS >` shows it was started in JavaScript mode.

You can start `mysqlsh` with `--sql` to start in SQL mode:

```
mysqlsh --sql mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html#option_mysqlsh_sql